# Create Snowflake stored procedure using multiple CTEs and insert the final CTE output into a table

Tags: stored-procedures, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have a situation where I have used multiple CTE statements and I want to insert my final CTE output into a table in a stored procedure - is this possible? If yes - how?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp5()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
  $$

  var my_sql_command = 'with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (select emp_name,emp_id  from TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11)
  insert into TEST_1.PUBLIC.EMP1 (emp_name,emp_id)  select emp_name,emp_id from ct2';
  
  var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );

  var result_set1 = statement1.execute();


  return  "Done";
  $$;
  
 call sp5();
```

**Error**

> JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in SP5 at ' var my_sql_command = 'with ct2 (emp_name, emp_id) as (select emp_name, emp_id from TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11)' position 23

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use INSERT INTO together with CTE.

Instead of:

```
with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (
     select emp_name,emp_id from TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11
) 
insert into TEST_1.PUBLIC.EMP1 (emp_name,emp_id) 
select emp_name,emp_id from ct2
```

use:

```
insert into TEST_1.PUBLIC.EMP1 (emp_name,emp_id) 
with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (
     select emp_name,emp_id from TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11
) 
select emp_name,emp_id from ct2
```

Comment: Hey Lukasz...above piece of code was executing fine but when inserted inside a stored procedure it was throwing error, so i used \n\.

"INSERT INTO TEST_1.PUBLIC.EMP1 \n\
with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) AS (\n\
     SELECT emp_name,emp_id FROM TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11\n\
) \n\
SELECT emp_name,emp_id FROM ct2";

Comment: Appreciate you help....Lukasz

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that javascript isn't handling the variable correctly. It doesn't know what to do with the newline in your query string.

Try this. The difference is using a "backtick" (left of the 1 key) instead of a single quote to denote a javascript multi-line string.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp5()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
  $$

  var my_sql_command = `with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (select emp_name,emp_id  from TEST_1.PUBLIC.TEST11)
  insert into TEST_1.PUBLIC.EMP1 (emp_name,emp_id)  select emp_name,emp_id from ct2;`;
  
  var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );

  var result_set1 = statement1.execute();


  return  "Done";
  $$;
  
 call sp5();
```

Comment: Thanks David G....its working  :)

Comment: make sure to mark correct answers as accepted for anyone else who comes to this later ;)